i'm trying to fetch data from mongodb atlas collection and display it in react front end
I've made a server.js in my npx cra project that's connecting to atlas cluster and formatting the received data using a schema.
The data is about solar generation data I've downloaded from kaggle and uploaded to the solar collection using mongodb compass.
I ran into a problem when I tried to fetch the data and visualize it using graphs.
Using a graph component it keeps showing a single document regardless of date range.
Here's my server.js:
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    dbName: 'solargenerationdata'
})
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
    .catch((err) => console.error('Failed to connect to MongoDB:', err));

const GenerationDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    DATE_TIME: String,
    PLANT_ID: String,
    DC_POWER: Number,
    AC_POWER: Number,
    DAILY_YIELD: Number,
    TOTAL_YIELD: Number,
});

const GenerationDataModel = mongoose.model('solar', GenerationDataSchema, 'solar');

// Modified API endpoints
app.get('/api/generation_data/summary', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const startDate = req.query.startDate || new Date(Date.now() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString();
        const endDate = req.query.endDate || new Date().toISOString();

        const data = await GenerationDataModel.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    DATE_TIME: {
                        $gte: startDate,
                        $lte: endDate
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        date: { $substr: ["$DATE_TIME", 0, 10] },
                        plantId: "$PLANT_ID"
                    },
                    avgDcPower: { $avg: "$DC_POWER" },
                    avgAcPower: { $avg: "$AC_POWER" },
                    totalDailyYield: { $max: "$DAILY_YIELD" },
                    maxTotalYield: { $max: "$TOTAL_YIELD" }
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: { "_id.date": 1 }
            }
        ]);

        console.log('Summary Data:', data); // Log the fetched data
        res.status(200).json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server Error' });
    }
});

app.get('/api/generation_data/latest', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const latestData = await GenerationDataModel.findOne()
            .sort({ DATE_TIME: -1 });

        console.log('Latest Data:', latestData); // Log the fetched data
        res.status(200).json(latestData);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server Error' });
    }
});

const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

and graphcomponent.js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { CartesianGrid, Legend, Line, LineChart, ResponsiveContainer, Tooltip, XAxis, YAxis } from 'recharts';

const GraphComponent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [latestData, setLatestData] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState({
        from: new Date(Date.now() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        to: new Date(),
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                setLoading(true);
                setError(null);
                
                const params = new URLSearchParams({
                    startDate: dateRange.from.toISOString(),
                    endDate: dateRange.to.toISOString(),
                });
                
                // Fetch summary data
                const summaryResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/generation_data/summary?${params}`);
                if (!summaryResponse.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${summaryResponse.status}`);
                }
                const summaryData = await summaryResponse.json();

                // Process summary data
                const formattedData = summaryData.map(item => ({
                    date: new Date(item.DATE_TIME).toLocaleDateString(),
                    plantId: item.PLANT_ID,
                    dcPower: Number(item.DC_POWER) || 0,
                    acPower: Number(item.AC_POWER) || 0,
                    dailyYield: Number(item.DAILY_YIELD) || 0,
                    totalYield: Number(item.TOTAL_YIELD) || 0
                }));

                // Group by date and calculate averages
                const groupedData = formattedData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                    const existingEntry = acc.find(item => item.date === curr.date);
                    if (existingEntry) {
                        existingEntry.dcPower += curr.dcPower;
                        existingEntry.acPower += curr.acPower;
                        existingEntry.dailyYield += curr.dailyYield;
                        existingEntry.count += 1;
                    } else {
                        acc.push({
                            date: curr.date,
                            dcPower: curr.dcPower,
                            acPower: curr.acPower,
                            dailyYield: curr.dailyYield,
                            count: 1
                        });
                    }
                    return acc;
                }, []);

                // Calculate final averages
                const finalData = groupedData.map(item => ({
                    date: item.date,
                    avgDcPower: Number((item.dcPower / item.count).toFixed(2)),
                    avgAcPower: Number((item.acPower / item.count).toFixed(2)),
                    totalDailyYield: Number((item.dailyYield / item.count).toFixed(2))
                })).sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));

                // Fetch latest data
                const latestResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/generation_data/latest');
                if (!latestResponse.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${latestResponse.status}`);
                }
                const latestDataResponse = await latestResponse.json();
                
                setData(finalData);
                setLatestData(latestDataResponse);
                setLoading(false);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error in fetchData:', error);
                setError(`Error fetching data: ${error.message}`);
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [dateRange]);

    const handleDateChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setDateRange(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            [name]: new Date(value)
        }));
    };

    if (loading) {
        return (
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-64">
                <div className="animate-spin rounded-full h-8 w-8 border-b-2 border-gray-900"></div>
                <span className="ml-2">Loading data...</span>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="space-y-6 p-4">
            {error && (
                <div className="bg-red-50 border-l-4 border-red-400 p-4 rounded">
                    <div className="flex">
                        <div className="ml-3">
                            <h3 className="text-sm font-medium text-red-800">Error</h3>
                            <div className="mt-2 text-sm text-red-700">{error}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}

            {/* Date Range Selection */}
            <div className="bg-white p-4 rounded-lg shadow">
                <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-4">Select Date Range</h2>
                <div className="flex gap-4">
                    <div>
                        <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">From</label>
                        <input
                            type="date"
                            name="from"
                            value={dateRange.from.toISOString().split('T')[0]}
                            onChange={handleDateChange}
                            className="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">To</label>
                        <input
                            type="date"
                            name="to"
                            value={dateRange.to.toISOString().split('T')[0]}
                            onChange={handleDateChange}
                            className="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* Current Metrics */}
            {latestData && (
                <div className="bg-white p-4 rounded-lg shadow">
                    <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-4">Current Solar Generation Metrics</h2>
                    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
                        <div className="p-4 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg">
                            <h3 className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">Plant ID</h3>
                            <p className="text-2xl font-bold">{latestData.PLANT_ID || 'N/A'}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="p-4 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg">
                            <h3 className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">Daily Yield</h3>
                            <p className="text-2xl font-bold">{latestData.DAILY_YIELD?.toFixed(2) || '0'} kWh</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="p-4 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg">
                            <h3 className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">Total Yield</h3>
                            <p className="text-2xl font-bold">{latestData.TOTAL_YIELD?.toFixed(2) || '0'} kWh</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}

            {/* Power Generation Trends */}
            {data.length > 0 ? (
                <div className="bg-white p-4 rounded-lg shadow">
                    <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-4">Power Generation Trends</h2>
                    <div className="h-[400px]">
                        <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
                            <LineChart data={data}>
                                <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                                <XAxis
                                    dataKey="date"
                                    tick={{ fontSize: 12 }}
                                    angle={-45}
                                    textAnchor="end"
                                />
                                <YAxis />
                                <Tooltip />
                                <Legend />
                                <Line 
                                    type="monotone" 
                                    dataKey="avgDcPower" 
                                    stroke="#8884d8" 
                                    name="Avg DC Power (kW)" 
                                    dot={false}
                                />
                                <Line 
                                    type="monotone" 
                                    dataKey="avgAcPower" 
                                    stroke="#82ca9d" 
                                    name="Avg AC Power (kW)" 
                                    dot={false}
                                />
                                <Line 
                                    type="monotone" 
                                    dataKey="totalDailyYield" 
                                    stroke="#ffc658" 
                                    name="Daily Yield (kWh)" 
                                    dot={false}
                                />
                            </LineChart>
                        </ResponsiveContainer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div className="bg-yellow-50 border-l-4 border-yellow-400 p-4">
                    <div className="flex">
                        <div className="ml-3">
                            <h3 className="text-sm font-medium text-yellow-800">No Data Available</h3>
                            <div className="mt-2 text-sm text-yellow-700">
                                No generation data available for the selected date range.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default GraphComponent;


thanks in advance for your help !

What is the current output? How does it look like? What is the expected output?
